# Block agent user from 12:30am to 2 am

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to block Twitterbot/1.0 agent user from 12:30am to 2 am cause it visits me a couple of times all night at 0:40am and 1:25 am more or less causing my server to fall 1 minute on both "strange crawling visits".

I have seen this code that says to block all from 4:00pm to 4:59pm and 8am

```
RewriteEngine On
# Multiple hour blocks
# If the hour is 4 PM or 5 PM or 8 AM
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} ^16|17|08$
# Then deny all access
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]
```

I´m not and expert on this kind of codes so how can I block an user agent or some ips instead of all?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written with your shown samples.
Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Twitterbot/1\.0 [NC]
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >=0030
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} <=0200
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

***NOTE:*** Also to check these set of Rules immediately you can keep your current time in these timings places for testing purposes so that you can instantly check them if they are working fine or not. Also change your agent name accordingly in case this is not the exact one in above Rules.

Comment: It´s seems not to be working. I have done this one: RewriteEngine ON RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Twitterbot/1\.0 [NC] RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >=2005 RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} <=2015 RewriteRule ^ - [F,L] Now at 20:24 Twitterbot agent still with 403 status. Any idea? I think the first two conditions works but not the third one.

Comment: Or maybe the only one working is the first one cause I have tested to share a tuit just to see the agent at 20:07 but not before 20:05

Comment: @RalAMORESGONZLEZ, I have used timings from 12:30 to 02:00 AM you could change timings accordingly and let me know how it went.

Comment: It seems the only one condition working is the fist one. I have now used timings from 21: 50 (writing >=2150) and 21:55 (writing <=2155) and twitterbot has been blocked at 21:48.

Maybe I´m not writing timing well? Maybe I have to used am-pm times and not 24h time?

Comment: Using your code literally it also block the agent although is 10pm in Spain.So then the only condition working is the first, the one referred to the agent so servet block it always :(

Comment: Hello my friend, now its working. I have deleted "=" from the code using only >hour1 and <hour2.

Many thanks for your help!!!

Comment: The expression `(x >=1230) AND (x <=0200)` can never be true. But 12:30am (12 hour clock) is 00:30 (24 hour clock). So it should be `(x >=0030) AND (x <=0200)`.

Comment: @MrWhite, thank you for nice catch I completely missed it, edited it now

Comment: @RalAMORESGONZLEZ "I have deleted `=` from the code" - If you had to remove `=` to get this to work (because the conditions were always successful, ie. you were getting a 403 regardless of "time") then it would seem to imply you are on a LiteSpeed server, not Apache?! (Conversely, an Apache 2.2 server would _always_ fail.) The `>=` and `<=` operators are new with Apache 2.4

Comment: @MrWhite yes, my server is a LiteSpeed one